# Measuring a rotating shaft's torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, mass

My question is, there is a rotating shaft and I want to measure its torque. I don’t know its $r$ and $F$ but I connected a thread to the end of shaft to see how much weight it can lift and it is 2 kilogram.
In this case how can I measure the shaft torque?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not know the radius - but perhaps you can see how far the object is lifted in a certain time. If you know the RPM of the shaft, you can use this to deduce the radius; and since you already know the force, this will give you the torque.

Assume velocity of lifting is $v$ and rate of rotation is $R$ (in RPM). Then angular speed of shaft is $\omega = R/(60*2\pi)$, and radius $r=v/\omega$. Finally, torque $\Gamma = F\;r$. So

$$\Gamma = F\;r = F \frac{v}{\omega} = \frac{2\cdot 9.81\cdot 120 \pi v}{R}$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that the force is 2Kg (multiply by $9.81 ms^{-1}$ for Newtons)

You need to measure the radius of the rod.

If the radius of your thread is significant you might want to include that.